# Python list comprehension difference in results

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, list-comprehension

I was working on list comprehensions in python 3. When I came across this behavior which I don't understand. Looking forward to learn from someone why this is happening.

```
>>> chess_board = [[(i,j) if(i not in (0,7) and j not in (0,7)) else '—-' for i in range(8)] for j in range(8)]
>>> # **behavior 1** : using for loop to print
>>> for row in chess_board:
...     print(row)
...
['—-', '—-', '—-', '—-', '—-', '—-', '—-', '—-']
['—-', (1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 1), (4, 1), (5, 1), (6, 1), '—-']
['—-', (1, 2), (2, 2), (3, 2), (4, 2), (5, 2), (6, 2), '—-']
['—-', (1, 3), (2, 3), (3, 3), (4, 3), (5, 3), (6, 3), '—-']
['—-', (1, 4), (2, 4), (3, 4), (4, 4), (5, 4), (6, 4), '—-']
['—-', (1, 5), (2, 5), (3, 5), (4, 5), (5, 5), (6, 5), '—-']
['—-', (1, 6), (2, 6), (3, 6), (4, 6), (5, 6), (6, 6), '—-']
['—-', '—-', '—-', '—-', '—-', '—-', '—-', '—-']
>>> # **behavior 2** using list comprehension
>>> [print(row) for row in chess_board]
['—-', '—-', '—-', '—-', '—-', '—-', '—-', '—-']
['—-', (1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 1), (4, 1), (5, 1), (6, 1), '—-']
['—-', (1, 2), (2, 2), (3, 2), (4, 2), (5, 2), (6, 2), '—-']
['—-', (1, 3), (2, 3), (3, 3), (4, 3), (5, 3), (6, 3), '—-']
['—-', (1, 4), (2, 4), (3, 4), (4, 4), (5, 4), (6, 4), '—-']
['—-', (1, 5), (2, 5), (3, 5), (4, 5), (5, 5), (6, 5), '—-']
['—-', (1, 6), (2, 6), (3, 6), (4, 6), (5, 6), (6, 6), '—-']
['—-', '—-', '—-', '—-', '—-', '—-', '—-', '—-']
[None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]
>>>
```

Why is there a row printing [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None] while printing using list comprehension?

Comment: you're using `print` in a list comprehension, is there a specific reason you are doing that?

Comment: try `print([row for row in chess_board])`

Comment: `print` returns `None`. Don't use a list comprehension just as a "short" version of a regular `for` loop.

Answer (score 5):

1/ list comprehensions (`[something for item in iterable]`) produce a `list`.

2/ `print()` returns `None`.

3/ Your Python shell always prints the result of the last expression that was evaluated.

So what you see is the result of your list expression.

FWIW, list comprehensions should NOT be used for side effects - it's a waste of resources, and it doesn't help with readability.

Answer (score 1):

Hi and welcome to Stackoverflow.

`print()` is a function and returns `None`. A list comprehension is building up a list.

You are building up a list by calling `print()` for each element in `chess_board`.

A side effect of `print()` is to write the row to standard output, and calling it repeatedly in the list comprehension makes it print out all the rows.

In the end, your expression returns a list with `None`s.

Since you are running this in an interactive shell, the results of expressions are printed out too:

```
>>> 1
1
>>> 1+1
2
>>> [a+1 for a in range(5)]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> [print(a+1) for a in range(5)]
1
2
3
4
5
[None, None, None, None, None]
>>>
```

The last row is just the result of the expression, that is, the list you constructed with the list comprehension expression.